# "By" or "In" + gerund?

Tags: gerunds

Should I say:

1. I've made a huge mistake **by** accepting this offer
2. I've made a huge mistake **in** accepting this offer

Comment: Google Books has about four times as many instances of [*made a mistake **in** agreeing to*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22made+a+mistake+in+agreeing+to%22) as [*made a mistake **by** agreeing to*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22made+a+mistake+by+agreeing+to%22), but that doesn't imply either is "right" or "wrong". It's just a stylistic choice, with no real semantic implications.

Comment: ...but note that *You are mistaken **by** thinking that* is a complete no-no. In that context, I think only *You are mistaken **in** thinking that* would be idiomatically acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a huge mistake by accepting this offer.

I have made a huge mistake in accepting this offer.

I think there's no difference in meaning between these sentences.

You usually use the structure mistake + in + -ing form. Even you can drop the preposition 'in' that's optional.

I have made a huge mistake accepting this offer.

It'll also  be grammatical if you say:

I made the huge mistake of accepting this offer.

As for the use of the preposition "by", though not as common as in, it's also correct in the sentence; we use it for stating the way we do something.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these choices are perfectly correct.  It is immaterial whether you choose **by** or **in** here, since the meaning really does change depending on your choice.

I suppose you could argue that the first choice **"by"** has a *nuanced* and *very slight* implication of a more passive acceptance, and the **"in"** has a *nuanced* and *very slight* implication of a more active acceptance, but, that arguement is really splitting hairs.

The choice between **by** and **in** here is entirely a personal choice based on the sound of the sentence, and not its meaning.  I hear both usages on a regular basis in my everyday life.